# HTML Button to Create text + button and then create more off that

Tags: php, html, button, dynamic, dropdownbox

So I am creating a website that tracks a user's Shooting Score for Rifle Competitions. I have a Create Match tab, which brings them to a page containing a
Weapon Selection drop down, then a Date input, then a Location input, and then I have a Save Match button which will send these three inputs to a database along with a uniqueID (primary key, auto incremented) which will allow them to distinguish which match is which.

Now for each match you can create a String of Fire which the user can select. So on the same page, I have when the user presses Save Match, it sends the data, and then brings up another Dropdown box which houses the 4 String of Fire modes (200 yd slow, 200yd rapid, 300yd rapid, 600yd slow). And then a Create String button next to that which will bring down 10 target scores they can fill in after they push the button. the problem I am having is that when this button is pushed, it deletes the Create String dropdown box and button as well, and I'm not entirely sure what's wrong. I think it has something to do with how I'm using POST and that I am just creating a dropdown + button when they push Save Match....

Sorry for the long block of text, I'll try to break it down more if that was too confusing.

So basically I want to be able to push the first button (And retain w/e the user put in which I have working), and then it brings up a dropdown with 4 entries and a button, and then when that second button is created, a table of 10 entries is brought up, with a Save button, and when THAT button is pushed, it sends the 10 entries to the database. I can get the database transfer stuff working, I just need the creating more functional buttons/text inputs to work first.

Thank you for your time!

Code for HTML

```
 <form name="table"  action ='' method="post">
 Rifle:
 <select name="wpn" id="wpn">
 <option>AR15</option>
 <option>HK416</option>
 <option>M1 Garand</option>
 <option>M14</option>
 <option>M4/M16</option>
 <option>M24</option>
 <option>SSG500</option>
 <option>SSG556</option>

</select>
Date: <input type="date" name = "date" id="date" value = "<?php echo $_POST['date']; ?    >">

 Location:<input type="text" name="loc" id="loc" value = "<?php echo $_POST['loc']; ?>" />

<button type="submit" name = "save" value="Save Match">Save Match</button>
```

Code for PHP

```
<?php
//if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
if($_POST['save'] == 'Save Match'){
    if($_POST["date"]==NULL){
        apologize("Please enter a valid date!");
    }
    else if($_POST["loc"]==NULL){
        apologize("Please enter a location!");
    }


    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $wpn = $_POST['wpn'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $loc =$_POST['loc'];



    //if(isset($_POST['button'])){
        if(query("INSERT INTO matches (id, weapon, date, location) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
    $id, $wpn, $date, $loc) === false){
        apologize("Sorry insertion of data failure!!!");
   }else{
       // redirect("../public/matches.php");
        //header("Location: ../public/matches.php");

        ?>
        <br /><br />

        Strings of Fire:
        <select name="mode" id="mode">
            <option>200 Yard Slow</option>
            <option>200 Yard Rapid</option>
            <option>300 Yard Rapid</option>
            <option>600 Yard Slow</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" name="save" value="Create String">Create String</button>
        <?php
        if(($_POST['save']) == 'Create String'){
            echo test;
        }

   }

}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this all in one PHP script?

Comment: yeah...im pretty sure its cause im using the else statement to create the Strings of Fire, cause after i push the button, it will POST again and it wont go in the else statement because it's not going through and trying to query anyway.

Comment: Well, you do have a syntax error in your date field -> the closing PHP tag is technically missing, since you have all those spaces between `?` and `>`. Should also not use the same name for both submit buttons.

Comment: If you're not against learning a bit of jQuery, I could come up with a walk-through with how to do this with Ajax.

Comment: i tried it with the same submit names and it didnt work so i was fiddling around, but naw, i'm open to learning new things!

Comment: I'll see your long question and raise you a longer answer! Kidding, but let me know if the answer makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a work-in-progress, but here goes.

I split what you've shown into two separate files; here's the UI page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Shooting Scores for Rifle Competitions</title>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
            body {
                background: #e8e8e8;
            }

            .step {
                width: 50%;
                margin: 1em auto;
                padding: 1em;
                background: #fff;
            }

            #step1 select.weapon,
            #step2 select.fire-string
            {
                width: 50%;
            }

            #step1 input.date
            {
                width: 10em;
            }

            #step3 ol.scores-list li
            {
                margin-bottom: 1em;
            }

            #step3 input.score
            {
                width: 8em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">  
           <?php
               require('process.php');
            ?>   

            <div id="step1" class="step">
                <form class="table" action="" method="post" id="step1-form" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Rifle:</label>
                        <select name="wpn" id="wpn" class="form-control weapon">
                            <option>AR15</option>
                            <option>HK416</option>
                            <option>M1 Garand</option>
                            <option>M14</option>
                            <option>M4/M16</option>
                            <option>M24</option>
                            <option>SSG500</option>
                            <option>SSG556</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo $_POST['date']; ?>" class="form-control date" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Location:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="loc" id="loc" value="<?php echo $_POST['loc']; ?>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" name="save-match" id="save-match" value="step1" class="btn btn-default">Save Match</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="step2" class="step hide">
                <form class="table" action="" method="post" id="step2-form" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Strings of Fire:</label>
                        <select name="mode" id="mode" class="form-control fire-string">
                            <option>200 Yard Slow</option>
                            <option>200 Yard Rapid</option>
                            <option>300 Yard Rapid</option>
                            <option>600 Yard Slow</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" name="save-string" id="save-string" value="step2" class="btn btn-default">Create String</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="step3" class="step hide">
                <form class="table" action="" method="post" id="step3-form" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Target Scores:</label>
                        <ol class="scores-list">
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" name="scores[]" class="form-control input-sm score" value="" />
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" name="save-scores" id="save-scores" value="step3" class="btn btn-primary">Save Scores and Finish!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {

                // http://api.jquery.com/on/
                $(document)
                    .on('click', '#save-match', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var button = $(this);
                        // http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
                        var form = $('#step1-form').serialize()
                            + '&'
                            + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
                            + '='
                            + encodeURI(button.attr('value'));

                        // http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
                        $.post('/process.php', form)
                            .done(function (result, status, jqxhr) {

                                // http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/
                                $('#step1').slideToggle('slow', function () {

                                    // http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/
                                    $('#step2').removeClass('hide');
                                });
                            })
                            .fail(function () {
                            });

                    })
                    .on('click', '#save-string', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var button = $(this);
                        var form = $('#step2-form').serialize()
                            + '&'
                            + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
                            + '='
                            + encodeURI(button.attr('value'));

                        $.post('/process.php', form)
                            .done(function (result, status, jqxhr) {

                                $('#step2').slideToggle('slow', function () {

                                    $('#step3').removeClass('hide');
                                });
                            })
                            .fail(function () {
                            });

                    })
                    .on('click', '#save-scores', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var button = $(this);
                        var form = $('#step3-form').serialize()
                            + '&'
                            + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
                            + '='
                            + encodeURI(button.attr('value'));

                        $.post('/process.php', form)
                            .done(function (result, status, jqxhr) {
                                alert(result);
                            })
                            .fail(function () {
                            });

                    });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the server script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save-match']))
    {
        $is_valid = true;

        # step 1
        if(empty($_POST["date"]))
        {
            $is_valid = false;
            apologize("Please enter a valid date!");
        } 
        if(empty($_POST["loc"]))
        {
            $is_valid = false;
            apologize("Please enter a location!");
        } 

        if($is_valid)
        {   
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $wpn = $_POST['wpn'];
            $date = $_POST['date'];
            $loc =$_POST['loc'];

            if(!query("INSERT INTO matches (id, weapon, date, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", $id, $wpn, $date, $loc))
            {
                apologize("Sorry insertion of match data failure!!!");
            } 
            else 
            {
                # step 1 finished successfully.
            }
        }
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['save-string']))
    {
        # step 2
        if(empty($_POST["mode"]))
        {
            apologize("Please enter a valid mode!");
        } 
        else 
        {   
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $mode =$_POST['mode'];

            if(!query("YOUR QUERY HERE TO INSERT / UPDATE MODE", $id, $mode))
            {
                apologize("Sorry insertion of mode data failure!!!");
            } 
            else 
            {
                # step 2 finished successfully.
            }
        }
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['save-scores']))
    {
        echo "Received " . count($_POST['scores']) . " scores!";
        # step 3
        if(empty($_POST["scores"]))
        {
            apologize("Please enter your scores!");
        } 
        else 
        {   
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $scores = $_POST["scores"]; # this will be an array

            if(!query("YOUR QUERY HERE TO INSERT / UPDATE SCORES", $id, $scores))
            {
                apologize("Sorry insertion of scores data failure!!!");
            } 
            else 
            {
                # step 3 finished successfully.
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        # assuming a GET request at this point
    }
?>
```

I obviously have no idea what your `apologize()` or `query()` functions are. For sake of the example I'm choosing to assume `apologize()` simply echos a string, or perhaps throws an exception. The important bit is the script section at the end of the UI page:

```
$(function () {

    // http://api.jquery.com/on/
    $(document)
        .on('click', '#save-match', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var button = $(this);
            // http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
            var form = $('#step1-form').serialize()
                + '&'
                + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
                + '='
                + encodeURI(button.attr('value'));

            // http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
            $.post('/process.php', form)
                .done(function (result, status, jqxhr) {

                    // http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/
                    $('#step1').slideToggle('slow', function () {

                        // http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/
                        $('#step2').removeClass('hide');
                    });
                })
                .fail(function () {
                });

        })
        .on('click', '#save-string', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var button = $(this);
            var form = $('#step2-form').serialize()
                + '&'
                + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
                + '='
                + encodeURI(button.attr('value'));

            $.post('/process.php', form)
                .done(function (result, status, jqxhr) {

                    $('#step2').slideToggle('slow', function () {

                        $('#step3').removeClass('hide');
                    });
                })
                .fail(function () {
                });

        })
        .on('click', '#save-scores', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var button = $(this);
            var form = $('#step3-form').serialize()
                + '&'
                + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
                + '='
                + encodeURI(button.attr('value'));

            $.post('/process.php', form)
                .done(function (result, status, jqxhr) {
                    alert(result);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                });

        });
});
```

I've included links to each jQuery function where it's first used, so I'd recommend reading the manual for each one at some point. Here's what happens:

1. To begin, we bind "event listeners" for each of the submit buttons, using `.on()`. By hanging the listeners off of `document`, we can make sure the listeners still work even if the forms or buttons get replaced at some point. When using `.on()`, the first argument is the specific event we want to handle (in this case, the click event). The second argument defines a filter; basically, only handle a click event if an element matching that selector was the trigger. The last argument is a function to call when event needs to be handled.
2. Next, we get a reference to the button that triggered the event (which we'll use in a second). We then call jQuery's `.serialize()` on the relevant form for this button, which generates a form-encoded string we can use to post the form asynchronously (more on that in a minute). Unfortunately for our PHP script, the serialize function does not include the button in the string (for reasons beyond the scope of this question), so we have to manually append the relevant values to the string.
3. Continuing on, we use jQuery's `$.post()` function to send our serialized data to the server, where it will be processed as if it were a normal POST. `$.post()` has a few functions that we can use to handle the result of the POST; the two I mostly use are `.done()` and `.fail()`. `.done()` will be called if the request was successful (meaning it returned a 3xx HTTP code) and `.fail()` is called for 4xx or 5xx HTTP codes.
4. Finally, when receiving a successful response, we hide the current step and show the next, until we get to the last step. From there I would assume you either return to the initial view, or show some sort of success message...

I basically repeat the same logic for the three "steps" you've outlined. What this particular script does is hide and show each step as your user walks through it. It's obviously incomplete, so let me know where to elaborate.

**NOTE:** I've included links to CDN versions of both jQuery and Bootstrap (just to make the UI look a little less plain and take advantage of some helper classes).

Comment: hey man thanks for helping out! it looks great. I just had a couple questions about coding in php/html in general as well as this particular code.

To me it seems really hard separating the php and html because I don't really understand how to use the php in a separate file to communicate with the html. I understand HTML is static and is basically just the form you see on the website, and PHP is dynamic and can use the HTML forms to communicate data. But it seems confusing to me to separate them.

And Also for this code, When I click on submit, nothing happens, I thought the button would show?

Comment: I don't think the button is doing anything, there's no POST for the data. Don't I need like a <form action='' method="POST"> or is that not mandatory for a button to work?

Comment: If you're using the markup in my answer, each section is wrapped in it's own form. That makes it easier to serialize.

Comment: hah, fixed it,didn't notice the post request in the function. One last question, the check for null isn't working properly. I think it's because no matter what, when the button is pressed, it will execute the javascript functions anyway?

Comment: @Shinku443 If you're talking about the server check, it's most likely because checking for null isn't really the right action. We should be using the `empty()` function, since it handles both null entries (basically, the form value isn't present) and empty entries (form value is present, but it doesn't have a value). I'll update the code.

Comment: @Shinku443 Also, since we're using `echo` at a few points here, we should probably move the `require()` function down the HTML page, so that it displays somewhere inside the `<body>`.

Comment: before when I used the if $_POST['date'] == NULL it worked, and i changed it back to try it out, and it still didn't work, why would the empty work and not the POST==NULL?   Also why should the require moved down, isn't it better to have it at the top (similar to C coding style of headers at the top)? Yeah it didn't work with  the empty. It's because the javascript runs when the button is pushed regardless of the error-check on the form, is there a way to do like .on(click button) && $is_valid==true, then run the script?

Comment: No, the `require()` function does the same thing as `include()`, except that it throws an exception if the file can't be loaded. `include()` fetches and processes the file, outputting any HTML or whatnot to the stream as necessary. The reason to move it is because `echo` sends whatever string we supply as an argument directly to the output stream. So, you wind up with text being sent prior to even the doctype tag, the way my example is currently written.

Comment: As for why the null check doesn't work: comparing it to null or using is_null is really just checking whether the input was submitted, not if it has a value. Using empty() means you can check that it was submitted *and* that it has a non-empty value.

Comment: ahhh okay, but regardless the null-checking won't work, and when I get to the 10 inputs, I get some weird error, when I'm inputting numbers the row number (1-10) disapperas and the entire form slowly shrinks, and then I get a popup when I submit saying "Received 10 Scores!<br> fatal error, Unknown column 'Array' in 'fieldlist' in ...", and then it gives me my functions.php | | |  trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR); this is the line it says i'm getting an error for.

Comment: Might be better if you create a doc on http://collabedit.com/ and show me what you're doing, and then I can amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: does your error checking work? I didn't change anything from your code

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "error checking". The scripts, as-is, will only work if, say, your apologize() function throws an exception or otherwise returns a "bad" error code. Anything else is a successful post, meaning it returns a 2xx or 3xx response code. If that happens, the jQuery part assumes it's okay to proceed to the next step. The error you mention above is probably due to me not having a clue what your query() method does. I can adjust the sample code if you amend your question to include (at a high level, at least) what apologize() and query() do.